# Получить присвоенное значение автоинкремента после вставки в LiteDb

Tags: c#, nosql

Возможно ли при выполнение `insert`'a получить индекс который был выдан записи.
Реализация `insert`'a через модель:

```
class Test
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string str1 { get; set; }
  public string str2 { get; set; }

  public void insert()
  {
      using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"LocalBD.db"))
      {
          var col = db.GetCollection<Test>("Test");
          col.Insert(new Test { str1 = this.str1, str2 = this.str });
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: ну судя по исходникам собственно Insert возврщает BsonValue, которое и есть id. Остаётся привести его к числовому типу. `int id = col.Insert(new Test { str1 = this.str1, str2 = this.str }).AsInt`

Comment: это если вы не меняли поведение фичи AutoId, которое так же может юзать Guid-ы или даты

Comment: @4per Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по исходникам, собственно Insert возвращает BsonValue, которое и есть автосгенерированное id. Остаётся привести его к числовому типу.

```
int id = col
    .Insert(new Test { str1 = this.str1, str2 = this.str })
    .AsInt;
```

Это если вы не меняли стандартных настроек, при которых функция LiteDb, именуемая AutoId, генерирует автоинкрементные значения для документов, в которых отсутствует поле Id. Настройки позволяют использовать как id GUID-ы или даты.